# ASP.NET Core .css Extension Goes To Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I migrate my ASP.NET application to ASP.NET Core.

> http://localhost:56623/js/jquery.js

works fine but

> http://localhost:56623/css/bootstrap.css

calls my CategoryController's CheckIsCustomPage action so my application raise exception of course.

What can i do?

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Category",
        template: "{sefLink}/{pageNumber}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "CheckIsCustomPage", pageNumber = "1" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Ajax",
        template: "ajax/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Ajax" });

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you don't have [static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2) configured. If your routing is coming into play that's after the point that static files should be served. Prior to your:

```
app.UseMvc ...
```

Make sure you have:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

And that your `css` folder is under `wwwroot`

Comment: I put css files to "Content" folder as my old ASP.NET applications. But i've changed folder to css it works now. Thank you.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2